# Using CSS variable with styled-components

Tags: css, styled-components

I know you can wrap your react app with `<ThemeProvider />` and you can set a variable for the theme and access it like so:

```
const Text styled`
   color: ${((props) => props.theme.red)};
`
```

But it's it CSS itself have the variable feature?

You can just do

```
:root {
  --red: tomato; 
}
.text {
  color: var(--red);
}
```

is it ok to mix them? or stick to either styled-components or CSS?

Comment: Yes it is OK. Those 2 technologies have nothing to do with each other and are not conflicting

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is OK. Those 2 technologies have nothing to do with each other and are not conflicting.

As long as your components can inherit the CSS variables (AKA custom properties) they will work.

Just make sure they are really inherit.

Clearly defining variables on the root element selector (`html`) will make them available everywhere, but sometimes you don't want global variables, but more local, per page/area/component, so you need to structure you code taking that into account.

The real power of CSS variables is in their inheritance (unlike SCSS variables which are injected/replaces during the build-process).

The power of styled-components is isolation & the ability to share code with javascript. This does hinder their ability to inherit CSS variables defined at parents-level.

You need not bother yourself with this question at all, and simply ignore the fact you are using `styled-components`. All that matters is the HTML structure, which how inheritance works.

#### I Googled things for you:

1. https://medium.com/fbdevclagos/how-to-leverage-styled-components-and-css-variables-to-build-truly-reusable-components-in-react-4bbf50467666
2. https://betterprogramming.pub/7-ways-to-inherit-styles-using-styled-components-69debaad97e3
3. https://dev.to/arnonate/using-css-variables-to-tame-styled-component-props-2f9o

Comment: theme variable like font size and color should be global no?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, in the sense of high-level colors & sizes definitions, but **no** in the sense of more area-specific variables definitions. For example `--red-100: #FF0000;` is a high-level color variable, but `--danger-color: red' is more local and should derive from the higher-level, more "raw" colors variables. It's all about breaking things down, splitting the areas of responsibilities and not making a mess out of your theme.